# Distributions with undefined parameters

Tags: distributions, hierarchical-bayesian, inverse-gaussian-distribution

I am studying the Bayesian Lasso and noticed something interesting on Page 682 at the bottom of the second column [here](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/archived/casella/Papers/Lasso.pdf)

Some background: a hierarchical setup for data $X, y$, regression coefficients, $\beta_i$, variance $\sigma^2$ and additional parameters $\tau^2_i$ is setup leading to an intractable posterior. The goal is to implement a Gibbs sampler to sample from the posterior, and thus this requires full conditionals.

The full conditional for each $\tau^2_i$ is

$$
\dfrac{1}{\tau^2_i} \mid (\beta, \sigma^2, y) \sim \text{Inverse Gaussian} \left(\sqrt{\dfrac{\lambda^2 \sigma^2}{\beta_i^2}}, \lambda^2  \right)
$$

where $\lambda^2$ is a fixed quantity $ > 0$. The support of $\sigma^2$ and $\tau^2_i$ is $\mathbb{R}^+$, but the support of $\beta_i$ is $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $\beta_i$ could be 0, leading to an undefined first argument in the Inverse Gaussian.

My question is: How is this not a problem?

Comment: With a continuous distribution, the probability that beta equals zero is zero, so it's not a problem. Same thing for "a" in N(1/a,1). In this latter case, draw a from its distribution and then draw X from its conditional distribution and see what you get. If the distribution for a is continuous, you'll "never" draw a = 0. (Computers are finite state machines, so I suppose it's possible if you make enough draws, but you can treat that as  a "mistake" and discard it.)

Comment: I understand that observing $\beta_i = 0$ or $a = 0$ is a 0 probability event, so in practice, that is never going to be a problem. I am wondering how mathematically those distributions are still valid.

Comment: I'm not the guy to provide proofs.

Comment: @Greenparker the answer is simple: they are not. How would you imagine normal distribution centered at undefined mean?

Comment: @Tim that's what I thought. Then how is the Gibbs sampler in the Bayesian Lasso valid? I see no mention of this in any of the Bayesian Lasso papers.

Comment: @Greenparker I didn't have time to read the paper carefully, but for sampler it is not a problem to simply reject cases with zeros and make new draws (as mef already said, since exact zero is very unlikely this does not influence the performance)...

Comment: @Tim the implementation I am not worried about, but the theoretically, if the Markov chain transition kernel is undefined, then how will it guarantee convergence to the stationary distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the answer lies in looking at the pdf of the Inverse Gaussian.

The full conditional for each $\tau^2_i$ is
$$\dfrac{1}{\tau^2_i}| \beta, \sigma^2, y \sim \text{Inverse Gaussian}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{\lambda^2 \sigma^2}{\beta_i^2}}, \lambda^2  \right). $$

\begin{align*}
f(\tau^2_i | \beta, \sigma^2, y) & = \sqrt{\dfrac{\lambda^2}{2 \pi}} \left( \tau^2_i\right)^{-1/2} \exp \left\{\dfrac{-\beta_i^2 \left(1 - \tau^2_i \sqrt{\frac{\lambda^2 \sigma^2}{\beta^2_i}} \right)}{2 \sigma^2\tau_i^2}  \right\}\\
& = \sqrt{\dfrac{\lambda^2}{2 \pi}} \left( \tau^2_i\right)^{-1/2} \exp \left\{\dfrac{-\beta_i^2 - (\tau^2_i)^2\lambda^2 \sigma^2 + 2\tau^2_i \lambda \sigma\beta_i}{2 \sigma^2 \tau^2_i}  \right\}
\end{align*}

If $\beta_i = 0$, then 
\begin{align*}
f(\tau^2_i | \beta, \sigma^2, y) & =\sqrt{\dfrac{\lambda^2}{2 \pi}} \exp \left\{ -\dfrac{\lambda^2}{2}\tau^2_i \right\}.
\end{align*}

Thus, $$\tau^2_i | \beta, \sigma^2, y \sim \text{Gamma}(1/2, \lambda^2/2) \text{ and } \dfrac{1}{\tau^2_i} | \beta, \sigma^2, y \sim \text{Inverse Gamma}(1/2, \lambda^2/2).  $$

So when the mean parameter of the Inverse Gaussian distribution is undefined, or in particular of the form $1/0$, the distribution turns out to be an Inverse Gamma distribution!I am sure it has something to do with the [generalized inverse Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse_Gaussian_distribution), but exactly what, I am not sure. This is an *extremely* surprising result.